# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 1 - While having multiple Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

While using swift UICollectionView with FlowLayout whenever I am trying to insert to delete cell (having 2 supplementary header section )it is giving below error :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 1.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

1. Initially my UIcollection view has just two sections on display.
2. Then on user action I am adding items under section 0 or section 1 which depends on items category.

Whenever I make section as 1 insertItemsAtIndexPaths & deleteItemsAtIndexPaths are working fine. I am using IOS9 and swift . Have seen lots of post and tried things but have been stuck here.
    var selectedPlayerDispCollection =  [(String, PlayersProfile)]

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView!) -> Int {
        return 2
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!,numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return selectedPlayerDispCollection.count
}

func performBatchUpdates(updates: (() -> Void)?,
    completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?){
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

**// For now adding in section 0 , depending on condition will add in section 0 or section 1
    func addPlayerView(playertapped : PlayersProfile) {
    let count = selectedPlayerDispCollection.count
    //let index = count > 0 ? count - 1 : count
    let index = count
    let playerDisSec = [(playertapped.playerSpeciality, playertapped)]
    selectedPlayerDispCollection.insert(playerDisSec, atIndex: index)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}**


/*func addPlayerView(playertapped : PlayersProfile) {
     let count = selectedPlayerDispCollection.count
      let index = count > 0 ? count - 1 : count
        selectedPlayerDispCollection.insert(playertapped, atIndex: index)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
        collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}*/
```

Comment: You tell the collectionview to delete **1** item and delete one item from the backing array. But on the other hand you use the array.count to determine the number of elements in both sections - which results in a removal of 1 item from the array causing the collectionview to have **2** cells less. Either separate the data between the sections or delete two items.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment already said: The problem is that you use one array to determine the number of items in both sections. Therefore removing one item from the array causes the collectionview to "lose" two cells. That losing of two cells does not add up with what you told the collectionView: remove one cell at indexPath abc.

**Solution 1**

Use two separate arrays as backing for each section or one array with sub-arrays.

**Solution 2**

Tell the collectionview to delete/add two items:

```
if let index = selectedPlayerDispCollection.indexOf(playertapped){
    let indexPath0 = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    let indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 1)
    selectedPlayerDispCollection.removeAtIndex(index)
    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath0, indexPath1])
}
```

You have to use the same logic when adding new items.

Comment: Initially my UIcollection view has just two sections on display.
Then on user action I am adding items under section 0 or section 1 which depends on items category.   I have updated my code in my question for insertItems.

Comment: As per my mentioned comment I am trying to do operation in one section item only. Please suggest what can be done?